# How to check if (unmanaged) file exists?

Tags: 7, files

I can't find a Drupal API function in D7 that tells me if an (unmanaged) file exists. 
D6 had a [file_check_location](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_check_location/6) but not for 7.

How to check if (unmanaged) file exists?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You could just use the old bog standard PHP function [`file_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) if I understand you right:

```
$uri = 'public://images/an-image.jpg';
if (file_exists($uri)) {
  // Do something
}
```

This also works for normal (absolute) paths as well, e.g.:

```
$path = '/var/www/drupal/sites/default/files/images/an-image.jpg';
if (file_exists($path)) {
  // Do something
}
```

Comment: Clive to the rescue again, thanks! Can I hire you? ;-)

Comment: @MotoTribe Depends how much you're offering ;)

Comment: Why does this work? I just tested this with plain PHP and a stream handle thrown into `file_exists()` and it does **not** work. Any explanation?

Comment: Because the streams have been properly registered by Drupal @kaiser. See http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php

Comment: @Clive I hoped you can point me to the source in Drupal. The rest I know and can not get working in a plain PHP test, hence I asked. **Edit:** nvm, [found them](https://github.com/drupal/drupal/tree/1d591ebe1dcc492ceef5e88febcdcc3f04e1e8a7/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StreamWrapper)

Comment: I like this method as a it saves the server from performing an http request and, in cases where the resource is not found, doesn't pollute my logs.

Answer (score 7):

If you want a Drupal way to do this, you can in Drupal 8/9/10 using the file_system service.

```
/** @var \Drupal\Core\File\FileSystemInterface $file_system */
$file_system = \Drupal::service('file_system');
$file_exists_error = $file_system->getDestinationFilename($file_uri, \Drupal\Core\File\FileSystemInterface::EXISTS_ERROR);
```

If the file does not exist in the file system $file_exists_error will return the file path, otherwise it will return false, denoting there was no error.

@see https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21File%21FileSystemInterface.php/function/FileSystemInterface%3A%3AgetDestinationFilename/9.3.x

Comment: In Drupal 10 you can just call file_exists on a public://path/to/file uri and it will return correctly since Drupal registers the stream wrappers at bootstrap

Answer (score 4):

I don't know what your specific use case is, but you may not need to check to see if the file exists.

The functions file_unmanaged_copy, file_unmanaged_move, file_unmanaged_delete, file_unmanaged_delete_recursive, and file_unmanaged_save_data check to see if the file exists and return false if it does not.

You can find the source code in drupal/includes/file.inc and have a look.

Answer (score 4):

You should use the drupal function:

file_destination($uri, FILE_EXISTS_ERROR)

and check

```
if (!file_destination($uri, FILE_EXISTS_ERROR)) {
  // The file exist
  // Do something
}
```

Comment: It will work as `file_destination()` uses `file_exists()` function