# How to load file, when I know it's filename, but not fid?

Tags: 7, files

I create filenames using some ID and timestamps. I don't want to add additional table to "remember" associations, as filename keeps them pretty well:

```
$filename = get_symbol_by_id($id) . ' ' . get_modified_by_id($id) . '.xml';
```

Also, I don't care if they will be managed or not. And I don't care if they get deleted - I can recreate them on demand. They are small, so leaving older ones behind does not create any cost worth taking care of. What is the proper course of action?

**"Unmanaged" files seems to be generally discouraged in 7**, but using them is pretty straightforward with tools like:

- [`file_unmanaged_save_data`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_unmanaged_save_data/7)
- `file_exists($uri)` in a manner shown [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/24233/16495)
- [`file_transfer`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_transfer/7) takes `$uri`, not `$fid`, so it's even easier to use it on unmanaged files

With managed files, I'm afraid I would be forced to use

- [`EntityFieldQuery`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7), overly complicated for such simple task or
- `$conditions` in [`file_load_multiple`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_load_multiple/7), marked as deprecated.

So what's the proper course of action, if I want to avoid both deprecated functionality and overly complicated code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd definitely go with [EntityFieldQuery](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7), not a really complicated solution:

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'file')
      ->propertyCondition('filename', '<filename>%', 'LIKE');
$result = $query->execute();
if (!empty($result['file'])) {
  $files = entity_load('file', array_keys($result['file']));
}
```

Use of conditions is not really recommended on any load multiple function anymore, the method above would be more standard and "future proof" as [EntityQuery](https://drupal.org/node/1827278) is the way to go in Drupal 8.

Installing [file entity module](https://drupal.org/project/file_entity) would add much more value on what you can do regarding managed files.

Comment: Small improvement would be to use `db_like()` to prepare the string, but yeah EFQ is the way forward